# Move files with certain name to folder with certain name - Unix

Tags: unix

I am trying since a while now, can anyone help me please?

I want to move files with certain names, e.g.

tree.txt  
apple.txt 
....

To their corresponding folder

tree 
apple

I tried this but it takes too much time to do it individually:

mv *****tree***** destination_directory/tree

because then I need to repeat this 200 times

mv *****apple***** destination_directory/apple

.....

Is there any way to make this faster?
I have a list.txt with all the file names.

Thank you so much,
Bine

Comment: There's a tool called `mmv`, where you can define placeholders in the source path that you can then reference in the target path (`mmv '*.txt' 'target/#1'` or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming toy have the list of txt files in a file called "filewithtxts", you can read the file into a while loop and then process each entry

```
while read file;
do
   dir=$(awk -F_ '{ print $(NF-1)"_"$NF }' <<< "${file%.txt}")
   mv *"${file%.txt}"* "destination_directory/$dir"   # Use ${file%.txt} to strip .txt from the entry 
done < filewithtxts
```

Comment: I think it doesnt work. The files have a long name like 343_dkf_3434_tree.txt. And the folders are then called tree. So I need to catch the files by their last ending before .txt somehow

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference to ${file%.txt}

Comment: Thank you but I am trying but the files dont move..  Actually it is like this 343_dkf_INTP_tree.txt and the folder called "INTP_tree".. So it needs to catch the last two words..

Comment: OK, I've amended the solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts, but unfortunately still the files dont move..

Comment: while read file;
do
   dir=$(awk -F_ '{ print $(NF-1)"_"$NF }' <<< "${file%.fastq.gz}")
   mv *"${file%.fastq.gz}"* "/exports/.../Test_Moving_Samples_to_Folders/$dir"   # Use ${file%.txt} to strip .txt from the entry 
done < Sample_Folders

Comment: And I run it with... qsub /exports.../Test_Moving_Samples_to_Folders/Move_samples_folder.sh